# Exception using stix-fonts with openjdk?

Tags: java, apache-poi, redhat

Problem happens while i try to create `SXSSFWorkbook` .

Exception stacktrace :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at sun.font.CompositeFont.getSlotFont(CompositeFont.java:351)
    at sun.font.CompositeGlyphMapper.initMapper(CompositeGlyphMapper.java:81)
    at sun.font.CompositeGlyphMapper.<init>(CompositeGlyphMapper.java:62)
    at sun.font.CompositeFont.getMapper(CompositeFont.java:409)
    at sun.font.CompositeFont.canDisplay(CompositeFont.java:435)
    at java.awt.Font.canDisplayUpTo(Font.java:2063)
    at java.awt.font.TextLayout.singleFont(TextLayout.java:470)
    at java.awt.font.TextLayout.<init>(TextLayout.java:531)
    at FontTest.main(FontTest.java:15)
```

gradle file :

```
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.14'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.14'
```

Environment :

- openjdk version "1.8.0_141"
- RedHat 7.4
- wildfly 10.0.0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue happened only on `Red hat version 7.4`.
it is reported [there](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3145721).
and the Red hat guys are working to fix it [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3145721). 
the solution I found is just to provide the  fonts   in order to force back Utopia as the default font, used by java.

Create the following file `/etc/fonts/local.conf` with the following content:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
  <alias>
    <family>serif</family>
    <prefer><family>Utopia</family></prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>sans-serif</family>
    <prefer><family>Utopia</family></prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>monospace</family>
    <prefer><family>Utopia</family></prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>dialog</family>
    <prefer><family>Utopia</family></prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>dialoginput</family>
    <prefer><family>Utopia</family></prefer>
  </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

Make sure the file is readable by the correct user.

Comment: Same solution works on `CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)` as well.
Just make sure to `sudo chmod 644 /etc/fonts/local.conf`