# How to solve exception [Error loading application.groovy due to [java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException]: 0] when deploying war?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, grails, centos7

How to solve exception occurred on war deployment to production mode

Development in Grails 3.1.8, Java 8

Deployment on Linux CentOS 7 and Tomcat 8.5.9 server.

Please find the error log from catalina.out

```
18-Mar-2018 20:29:21.953 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/application]]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)        
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Error loading application.groovy due to [java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException]: 0
            at org.grails.core.cfg.GroovyConfigPropertySourceLoader.load(GroovyConfigPropertySourceLoader.groovy:72)
            at org.grails.core.cfg.GroovyConfigPropertySourceLoader.load(GroovyConfigPropertySourceLoader.groovy:45)
            at org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourcesLoader.load(PropertySourcesLoader.java:127)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:462)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:449)    
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149)
            at org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85)
            at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5292)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
            ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
            at sun.font.CompositeFont.getSlotFont(CompositeFont.java:333)
            at sun.font.CompositeGlyphMapper.initMapper(CompositeGlyphMapper.java:81)
            at sun.font.CompositeGlyphMapper.<init>(CompositeGlyphMapper.java:62)
            at sun.font.CompositeFont.getMapper(CompositeFont.java:391)
            at sun.font.CompositeFont.canDisplay(CompositeFont.java:417)
            at java.awt.Font.canDisplay(Font.java:1980)
            at com.octo.captcha.component.image.fontgenerator.RandomFontGenerator.checkFontCanDisplayCharacters(RandomFontGenerator.java:207)
            at com.octo.captcha.component.image.fontgenerator.RandomFontGenerator.cleanFontList(RandomFontGenerator.java:163)
            at com.octo.captcha.component.image.fontgenerator.RandomFontGenerator.initializeFonts(RandomFontGenerator.java:79)
            at com.octo.captcha.component.image.fontgenerator.RandomFontGenerator.<init>(RandomFontGenerator.java:69)        
            at org.grails.core.cfg.GroovyConfigPropertySourceLoader.load(GroovyConfigPropertySourceLoader.groovy:61)
            ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
  at sun.font.CompositeFont.getSlotFont(CompositeFont.java:333)
```

This looks like some fonts are missing, or maybe none is installed. Compare the output of `fc-command` between your dev environment and your prod. This command might not be here by default and you need to install it too.
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46711597/exception-using-stix-fonts-with-openjdk) might help, as we don't know which distro you are running.

Comment: @Adell linux distro is centos 7.

Comment: ok, I edited your question. The answer I posted could be the right one.